# facebook canvas page not showing any data

Tags: php, facebook, canvas

I tried to create one canvas page on facebook

here is the config:
[image]

and for test I havent added any code in index php, i have just added:

**index.php**

```
<?php
echo "welcome to canvas";
?>
```

but on facebook page its not showing any data, please help to fix this

Comment: *sidenote:* you should have masked your App Secret.

Comment: any idea why its not working? any config issues ?

Comment: A dumb question: is your web server able to run PHP files?

Comment: yes if i copy canvas url to new window, then page working fine

Comment: I note that you didn't enter secure Page Tab URL. It's a required field now, and your server has to support HTTPS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41461/discussion-between-er-kt-and-shivan-raptor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Raptor, so bad mistakes here is that needs **https url** for canvas.